Stored procedure asynchronous execution: NotImplementedError: Async query is not supported in stored procedure yet
I'm trying to use the async job function in Python worksheet to test the asynchronous feature. But I'm getting an error

NotImplementedError: Async query is not supported in stored procedure yet

The same code I'm using in the Snowflake stored procedure. How to fix this error to achieve asynchronous execution?


You can run async queries as shown in the code when calling Snowflake from outside Snowflake. Once you put this code inside a stored procedure that runs inside Snowflake, then the async_() calls are not supported.
(When you are working in a Python worksheet inside Snowsight that code gets moved into a Stored Procedure to execute, hence the error)
